Why my SelectedItem from ListView isn't working?
This is code in wpf which shows the tour requests, arranged in two columns:
<ListView x:Name="TourRequestsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding TourRequests}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTourRequest, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                <Border BorderBrush="White" Background="#05085B" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" Width="500" Height="225">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Border Background="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource StateToBackgroundConverter}}" Margin="25,20,0,0" BorderBrush="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" Width="250">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="Status: " Margin="15,5,0,5" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Helvetica" Foreground="White"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding State}" Margin="0,5,5,5" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Helvetica" Foreground="White"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <Image Source="/wpf/icons/touristicons/schedule.png" Margin="25,20,0,0" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" FontFamily="Helvetica" Foreground="White" Margin="5,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Run Text="Creation Date: " />
                                <Run Text="{Binding CreationDate}" />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <Image Source="/wpf/icons/touristicons/number-blocks.png" Margin="25,20,0,0" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" FontFamily="Helvetica" Foreground="White" Margin="5,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Run Text="Number of simple tour requests: " />
                                <Run Text="{Binding NumberOfRequests}" />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <Button Content="See Details" Margin="0,20,0,0" Command="{Binding ElementName=TourRequestsListView, Path=DataContext.SeeDetailsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextDecorations="Underline" Cursor="Hand" FontFamily="Helvetica" FontSize="20" Foreground="Yellow"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

ItemsSource is binded to TourRequests and SelectedItem to SelectedTourRequest
C# (DataContext set to this viewModel):
private ObservableCollection<ComplexTourRequest> _tourRequests;
public ObservableCollection<ComplexTourRequest> TourRequests
{
    get
    { return _tourRequests; }
    set
    {
        _tourRequests = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TourRequests");
    }
}
private ComplexTourRequest _selectedTourRequest;
public ComplexTourRequest SelectedTourRequest
{
    get
    { return _selectedTourRequest; }
    set
    {
        _selectedTourRequest = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTourRequest");
    }
}

viewModel extends class with propertyChanged implementation:
public class ReviewComplexTourRequestsViewModel : TouristViewModel
TouristViewModel.cs:
public class TouristViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

When I debug, when clicking on an element from the list, only the get method is called, but not the set method, and selectedRourRequest returns null

This doesn't answer your question, but you don't need to strictly pass a string to the method OnPropertyChanged, because you have [CallerMemberName] as an argument to the function, so it will work without passing anything.

And also you need to make sure that the value of the setter is a type of ComplexTourRequest and not other type of variable.

Have you tried implementing the ItemClick="eventhandler" method on ListView? Or what does the SeeDetailsCommand do?

SeeDetailsCommand navigates to page with details for selected tour request. However, as the selected item returns null, the navigation definitely doesn't work.
I didn't try with ItemClick, because as far as I know it has to be done in code-behind, however, this project requires MVVM architecture, and in code behind I can only have DataContext setup. That's why I tried to do it through the selected item and the command SeeDetailsCommand.

The code you are showing here looks correct, and we can not tell why it won't work. Besides that, there is no need to use a ListView unless you set its View property. Use the simpler base class ListBox instead.

In the debugger if it isn't firing the OnPropertyChanged method when the selection changes you may need to change the UpdateSourceTrigger. I haven't used ListViews very often though.

the probability is that the routed event doesnt get to the ListView Item here is present. My suggested to add IsHitTestVisible="False" to elements which should ignore and pass throw the click/selection even. Because I ran the code you suggested and it work and the items are selected correctly.
